# VoiceGuidanceOptions issue

Tags: here-api

```
private final int EN_US_ID = 206;

VoiceGuidanceOptions voiceGuidanceOptions = navigationManager.getVoiceGuidanceOptions();
voiceGuidanceOptions.setTtsOutputFormat(NavigationManager.TtsOutputFormat.NUANCE);
voiceGuidanceOptions.setVoiceSkin(VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkin(EN_US_ID));
```

It says backslash tn most of the time even i have checked NewInstructionEventListener i am not getting where whats happening i donot need (backslash tn) in voice instruction what should i have to do please i am stuck need help

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for using EN_US_ID as "206" ? please try with below code snippet, \tn could be missing voice package

> if (!voiceCatalog.isLocalVoiceSkin(id)) {
>   voiceCatalog.downloadVoice(id, new OnDownloadDoneListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onDownloadDone(Error errorCode) {
>           if (errorCode == Error.NONE){
>             //voice skin download successful
>           }
>         }
>       }); }

Comment: I need in english which id should pass for localvoiceskin still it is saying blackslash TN